# Reporting Services: Creating user defined functions in report query. Is it real?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, user-defined-functions

Is it possible to create and use a user defined function in a report query?

Something like this:

```
if OBJECT_ID('userFunc', 'TF') is not null drop function userFunc
go

create function userFunc(@id int)
returns @tbl table
([id] int)
begin
insert into @tbl (id) values(@id)
return
end
go

select * from userFunc(1)

if OBJECT_ID('userFunc', 'TF') is not null drop function userFunc
```

When i run this query in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio it returns me 'id':1, but when i put this query into Reporting Query designer - i get the next error:

> TITLE: Microsoft Report Designer
>
> An error occurred while the query
>   design method was being saved.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'go'.
>
> 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first
>   statement in a query batch.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'go'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'userFunc'.

Any suggestions? **How to create and use udf in Reporting Services queries?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"GO" will [only be recognised by SQL tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971177/using-go-within-a-transaction/971199#971199): not the DB engine nor SSRS parser

This might if you really want to

```
EXEC 'if OBJECT_ID(''userFunc'') is not null drop function userFunc'
EXEC 'create function userFunc(@id int)
returns @tbl table
([id] int)
begin
insert into @tbl (id) values(@id)
return
end'
select * from userFunc(1)
```

However, you'll need ddl_admin or db_owner to run it.

Have you considered a CTE or derived table? A table valued udf like this can be replaced by a CTE

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it is exactly what i am looking for. 
This udf was created only like example, real udf is much more complicated.