# Why there is "GO" after USE db" in T-SQL examples?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking at the msdn, there was an example on "GO" command. Why there is:

```
USE somedb
GO
...
...
```

It it neccesary to select db in different batch? Thanks for explanation!

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905306/whats-the-meaning-of-the-go-statement-in-tsql

Comment: It is not. I know what is GO good for. But I cannot see any advantagee in using it after "USE db".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is it necessary to select db in
>   different batch?

No, however, **some** commands have to be the first statement in the batch.

Examples include `CREATE VIEW`, `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Thus if you want to do:

```
USE DB

CREATE VIEW X AS SELECT * FROM Y
```

Then you need to do:

```
USE DB
GO

CREATE VIEW X AS SELECT * FROM Y
```

If you are only running one `USE DB` statement, the `GO` has no usefulness.

Some commands do not require that they are the first statement in a batch:

```
USE DB
SELECT * FROM X
```

Sometimes in code generation, all the GO commands might not be necessary, but it's just easier to generate them.

Answer (score 2):

It signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.
You can check here for more details : [GO (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

Comment: I know and I was asking about GO after USE which is exactly on page you reference.