# Could not find stored procedure 'GO'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Quick question about running SQLServer scripts from a remote machine using JDBCs. I have a script that starts out as follows:

```
 USE MASTER
 GO

 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.SYSDATABASES WHERE NAME = 'MockData')
 DROP DATABASE MockData
 GO

 CREATE DATABASE MockData
 GO

 USE MockData
 GO
 ...
```

On the local machine I log in as my user and if I open this script file and execute it, it runs just fine. However, if I am on a different machine and connect using the Java JDBC driver (logged in as the same user) I get the following exception.

```
 Error executing: GO 
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'GO'.
```

Does anyone know why this would fail over JDBC but not on the local machine? Thanks

Comment: GO is not a SQL command, it is scripting command to separate commands in a query window.

Comment: Check this link out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668529/t-sql-go-statement

Comment: Sparky, I see what you are saying, but that post says I need to use go when I am dropping and creating things with the same name, like I am trying to do when I drop database MockData and than create it again.