# Effect of not specifyin GO in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know whether my stored procedure will get impacted without specifying `Go`

Here is the code flow:

```
Create or replace store_proc1
As
Begin
   While loop
    {SQL statements repeating itself until source table record count is 0}
   End
```

"Go"

Here I have missed `Go` at the end of my stored procedure.. Will it impact the performance?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668529/t-sql-go-statement

Answer (score 3):

`GO` is **not** a SQL statement - it's a **delimiter** used only in SQL Server **Management Studio**.

So no, omitting `GO` will **NOT** in any way affect your stored procedure's ability to run, nor it performance.