# Create Database and it's tables in 1 script

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL and have the follow problem:

I want 1 script where I create my database and its tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
USE TestDB
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
  CustomerID int NOT NULL,
  Company nvarchar(150) Not NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_CustomerID PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);
// further tables with same scheme like 'Customers'
```

With this script, I always get the error: TestDB is not existing...

I use SQL Server Express 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio

Thanks for help!

Comment: just type "Go" before "Use TestDB"

Comment: Try add the GO keyword between commands.

Comment: also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668529/what-is-a-batch-and-why-is-go-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
   GO
   USE TestDB
   GO
    CREATE TABLE Customers
    (
      CustomerID int NOT NULL,
      Company nvarchar(150) Not NULL,
      CONSTRAINT pk_CustomerID PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
    );
    // further tables with same scheme like 'Customers'
```