# Use GO (commit) in a SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, .net, commit, sqlcommand, executenonquery

When I use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` and its `CommandText` has a `GO` (commit) it it, I get an SQLException.

I removed it and the SQL worked, but the whole SQL has many statements and I'd like to commit after each of them run. And I don't wanna split them in multiple `SqlCommand` objects.

Is there a better solution to keep commiting and keep a unique `SqlCommand` object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GO` is not commit, it is the batch separator. You need to split your command batch into chunks and omit the `GO` in order to be able to execute them with `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Transaction handling is done independently. When you execute multiple commands in a loop, you are free to run them all in the same `SqlTransaction`, start a new transaction for every iteration, or leave the `SqlCommand.Transaction` property unassigned.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't understand what you mean. Do you suggest splitting the SQL string in multiple runs, right? I wanted to keep all the operations in a unique string and execute `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` once for them all. Is that really impossible?

Comment: It is possible, but you need to remove the `GO` lines. `GO` is not the same as a transaction commit. `GO` is interpreted by batch script processors (osql, SQL Studio script) to execute the code that precedes it as a unit, so you can for example chain multiple DDL statements like `CREATE VIEW` which is otherwise not possible. So if you just remove the `GO` you run a risk that the resulting script fails. I recommend a loop. You can still reuse the same `SqlCommand` object, just reassign the `CommandText`, with negligible performance penalty.

Comment: So, aren't logs commited to mdf files when a `GO` command is run? If that's the case, I'll just remove it and so be it.

Comment: yes and no :-) `GO` does not imply a transaction. you can execute a `BEGIN TRAN`, then run a batch, and then `ROLLBACK TRAN` to cancel the entire batch (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668529/what-is-a-batch-and-why-is-go-used). But if you don't use a transaction at all, every call to `SqlCommand.Execute()` will persist the results of its data manipulation immediately. In case you concat script parts previously separated by `GO`, be careful that you don't end up with an invalid script - some DDL operations like `CREATE PROCEDURE` cannot occur more than once in a single command).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my PowerShell solution:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") > $null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") > $null
$cnSQL=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=$($env:COMPUTERNAME)\$InstanceName;Database=master;User Id=$User;Password=$Pwd")
$cnServer=New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection($cnSQL)
$strSQL=Get-Content -Path "sqlFile.txt" | Out-String
$cnServer.ExecuteNonQuery($strSQL) > $null
$cnSQL.Close()
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your solution handles the problem of `GO` statements in the SQL script ?

Comment: You should explain that your solution only works if you have SQL Server installed on your machine btw.