# Temp Table creation is throwing error in same session even dropping and recreating also

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have below code. In this i am dropping and re-creating a same temp table in same session. But table is not getting dropped while creating it second time. It's throwing an error.Can any one help me with reason? Thanks in advance.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Table1','U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Table1
END
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([seller_name] varchar(3), [id_seller] int, [id_buyer] int)


INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([seller_name], [id_seller], [id_buyer])
VALUES
    ('abc', 1005, 1006),
    ('ddd', 1009, 1186),
    ('ccc', 1006, 1001),
    ('ccc', 1006, 1002),
    ('ddd', 1009, 1006),
    ('tyu', 1001, 1186)



GO

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Table1','U') IS NOT NULL --Not entering into `IF` block
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Table1
END
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([seller_name] varchar(3), [id_seller] int, [id_buyer] int, [id_buyr] int)


INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([seller_name], [id_seller], [id_buyer],[id_buyr])
VALUES
    ('abc', 1005,8,1006),
    ('ddd', 1009,8,1186),
    ('ccc', 1006,8,1001),
    ('ccc', 1006,8,1002),
    ('ddd', 1009,8,1006),
    ('tyu', 1001,8,1186)
```

go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add GO statement at the second time you create table.It's works

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Table1','U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Table1
END
GO
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([seller_name] varchar(3), [id_seller] int, [id_buyer] int, [id_buyr] int)


INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([seller_name], [id_seller], [id_buyer],[id_buyr])
VALUES
    ('abc', 1005,8,1006),
    ('ddd', 1009,8,1186),
    ('ccc', 1006,8,1001),
    ('ccc', 1006,8,1002),
    ('ddd', 1009,8,1006),
    ('tyu', 1001,8,1186)
;
```

Comment: Go is a signal for end of batch. So drop statement should be a separate one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Table1','U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Table1
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([seller_name] varchar(3), [id_seller] int, [id_buyer] int)


INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([seller_name], [id_seller], [id_buyer])
VALUES
    ('abc', 1005, 1006),
    ('ddd', 1009, 1186),
    ('ccc', 1006, 1001),
    ('ccc', 1006, 1002),
    ('ddd', 1009, 1006),
    ('tyu', 1001, 1186)
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Table1','U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Table1
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([seller_name] varchar(3), [id_seller] int, [id_buyer] int, [id_buyr] int)


INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([seller_name], [id_seller], [id_buyer],[id_buyr])
VALUES
    ('abc', 1005,8,1006),
    ('ddd', 1009,8,1186),
    ('ccc', 1006,8,1001),
    ('ccc', 1006,8,1002),
    ('ddd', 1009,8,1006),
    ('tyu', 1001,8,1186)
GO
```

Comment: Why that Go solves? Is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668529/what-is-a-batch-and-why-is-go-used - i do not know why - but - 'For example, you can't drop a table and re-create the same-named table in a single transaction, at least in Sybase'

Comment: I asked someone's opinion, and they said that a plan is built up for a batch and that the plan assumes constant table structures within the batch - if you want to change a table structure, you may need a new batch