# Is there benefit to breaking a large sql script into smaller batches?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm working on large and gnarly sql script that is pushing 500 lines. At the moment it is organized roughly like this.

```
-- Declare and set a couple of dozen variables that will be used in the script
-- Do lots of deletes, inserts, and updates
```

At the moment it is all done in a single batch. The reason is that many of the operations rely on common variables, and variables don't cross `GO` boundaries. Is there benefit to breaking a script like this up into smaller batches, even if it means redundantly re-declaring and re-setting some of the variables in each batch?

```
-- Declare a few variables
-- Run the delete, update, and insert operations that rely on those variables
-- GO

-- Declare a few variables, some new and some the same as from the previous batch
-- Run the delete, update, and insert operations...
-- GO

-- Rinse and repeat about a dozen times
```

Getting the values for the variables is inexpensive, usually setting them to literals or the result of `selecting` from tables with only 10s of rows.

Each of the deletes, updates, and inserts operate on sets of roughly 1 million to 5 million rows.

Is there a theoretical memory, storage (for the log files), and/or performance improvement that would be gained by breaking this up into multiple batches and that would outweigh the ugliness and annoyance of re-declaring and re-setting some variables multiple times?

What resources are out there to learn more about batches in this kind of situation? I know there are cases where batches are required, such as creating or updating tables before operating on the new tables/columns. The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668529/what-is-a-batch-and-why-is-go-used) question indicate that there may be some benefit for the size of the log file when using smaller batches. What I haven't been able to find is a definitive source of information on possible scenarios and performance benefits for using smaller batches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should. Split it into logical blocks.

For example:

```
 exec base_data
     can call exec base_data_address
     can call exec base_data_name
     can call exec base_data_date
```

- Easy to read.
- Easy to maintenance and debug.
- Easy to reuse procedure with parameters.
- Easy to control transaction flow.
- Easy to error handling.
- Easy to add new block.

If you have to send a lot of variables it seems something is wrong. For shortening code use views, functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Readability:-** Absolutely, It is far better to break them apart into several small easy to understand queries and helps to maintain.

**Performance:-** It varies, you have to look at the execution plan to be sure of this. SQL Server parallelism already does a very good job breaking down queries into multi-threaded searches but you are at least giving SQL a better chance to come up with a good query plan.

The one thing I have always gained from breaking down queries is that I do not get transaction log error if query is humongous and works well when broken down.

Comment: The OP does not speak about breaking large statements. I suggest reading the post again.