# Data Manipulation Language with and Without GO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of GO in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio)

### I have some Data Manipulation Language like below.

**Case - 1 Without GO**

```
Update Table
Set Columns = 'Value'
Where Id = 1

Update Table
Set Columns = 'Value'
Where Id = 2
```

---

**Case - 2 With GO**

```
Update Table
Set Columns = 'Value'
Where Id = 1

GO

Update Table
Set Columns = 'Value'
Where Id = 2
```

---

**Query**

Which should be preferred and why ?

Comment: If you disagree with this being a duplicate, state so in the comments and explain your point of view. But please don't just remove the "Possible duplicate" link at the top of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I got the differences in terms of Stored Procedure.

**Case 1 - When Select 2 is not the part and explicitly seperated from this stored procedure**

```
Create proc abc
as
select 1

GO

select 2
```

---

**Case 2 - When Select 2 is not the part of stored Procedure and by mistake became the part of stored procedure due to absence of GO**

```
Create proc abc
as
select 1

select 2
```

---

### In case 2 , Definition of the language becomes following.

```
Create proc abc
as
select 1

select 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference - that the 1st query runs in one turn since 2nd - in tho turns. GO delimiter is not a server command, it is just a batch separator, which should be handled by client.

This means - that 1st query performs better because of 1-turn query

Answer (score 0):

Refer below url it may help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx which states:

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements
>   entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or
>   script if this is the first GO.
>
> A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command.
>   However, the line can contain comments.
>
> Users must follow the rules for batches. For example, any execution of
>   a stored procedure after the first statement in a batch must include
>   the EXECUTE keyword. The scope of local (user-defined) variables is
>   limited to a batch, and cannot be referenced after a GO command.