# Sql Server Management studio drop table and re-create issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-drop

I have created a table with primary key and foreign key using SQL Server Management studio 2008R2, then I have drop the table using the sql command drop table nameofthetable and the table has been dropped.
After that I have created another table with the same name of the dropped table but I get this error:

> " The table 'name of my table' already exists'.

Why? I don't see the old table in my table list.

Can you help me, I need to create the table with this name?

Answer (score 1):

Commit your changes before you recreate the table. You can also use the [GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio) statement.

Answer (score 0):

In the Object Explorer, right-click and Refresh the Tables list

Comment: i resolved the issue closing management studio and reopening it

Comment: that would do it as well ... but, the refresh will avoid having to do that in the future.

Comment: @BWS Closing all tabs is necessary before you refresh the tables.