# Create database and table in a single .sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I do something like this:

```
Create Database mydb;
Create Table mydb.dbo.Customers
(
ID int,
FirstName varchar(255),
LastName varchar(255),
);
```

in a **single sql script** in SQL server managment studio ? It gives me the message `Database 'mydb' does not exist.`

[image: 1]

Edit: `use mydb;` after creating the database, doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
GO
USE mydb;
GO
CREATE TABLE mydb.dbo.Customers
    (
      ID INT ,
      FirstName VARCHAR(255) ,
      LastName VARCHAR(255),
    );
```

Comment: it seems that `Create Database mydb;  GO   CREATE Table.....` works as well. do you find that a better solution ?

Comment: @Shiro I wouldn't particularly care either version but keep in mind that the `GO` keyword is something that only works in SSMS. You cannot use the `GO` keyword within your application code, for example.

Answer (score 2):

use this command immediately after creating database (with `go`):

```
...
go
use myDb
go
```

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/739054205aae7c46b3c2be75bb79cf72.png  this is the error i got with your code, `Database 'mydb' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.`

Comment: Ok, just let me to review it

Comment: @Shiro, sorry I was in hurry and didn't notice you missed the `go` keywod, answer editted

Comment: it seems that `Create Database mydb; GO CREATE Table.....` works as well (just using 1 `go`) . do you find that a better solution ? it seems like `go` works as a batch separator, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio) i think this works well

Comment: what do you mean better solution? you mean for create database!? of course it's better to specify some other parameters like, file location, size, maxsize, etc, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)

Comment: No i mean that it is 2 lines less code this way. `Create Database mydb; GO CREATE Table...` **vs** `Create Database mydb; Go  use mydb;  Go   CREATE Table...`

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can change the `GO` to `;`, it's just a terminator