# SQL Incorrect Syntax Near 'GO'

Tags: sql, ssms

I am getting the error in my sproc and I cannot figure out why. I have looked at other, almost identical questions like this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190081/create-database-and-table-in-a-single-sql-script) and the answers aren't doing the trick for me. the syntax error is at the 'Go' right after the database creation.

```
USE [DATABASENAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sproc]
@Id int
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 
N'Name')

create database Name;

GO

CREATE TABLE [Name].[dbo].[Account](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AccountId] [int] NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: `GO` is not a qualified sql statement.. it is a batch separator for independent sql statements

Comment: I understand that, but I need to separate the db creation and the table creation or I will get a "Database does not exist error".

Comment: then you don't need `GO`

Comment: @Alfabravo do you know what you are suggesting?

Comment: you can only create a database on the fly if you have sufficient rights and you are in the `master` database

Comment: @Alfabravo Sorry, this is just a snippet of the beginning of the procedure. It is very long and the alter is closed. Also, "@Id" is not a variable, it is a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Robert , I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GO` is not allowed in stored procedures.  It separates batches and a procedure itself is one batch which cannot be separated.

You could use one procedure to create the database, then a second procedure to create the table.

**Edit**

Actually you could do it in one procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sproc]
AS
BEGIN

EXEC ('USE [Master]; CREATE DATABASE [name]')
EXEC ('USE [Name]; CREATE TABLE [name].dbo.[Account] (id int)')

END
```

Comment: I was thinking that may be the best way to do this. I appreciate your recommendation!