# SSMS query - script won't run if database does not exist

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I'm trying to do something like:

"If it exists, use it.  If not, create it."
"If it exists, delete it.  If not, create it."

One place it's definitely choking is the use it command - because if it DOES NOT EXIST - it chokes on the use command EVEN THOUGH that command will not run.

Here's more explanation:

---

I have a SQL Server script where I create a database and then I use the database.

The script will not run

- because the use database command is invalid
- because the database does not exist
- but it will exist after the first command executes
- but it doesn't matter because it doesn't exist NOW so the script will not run.

**How do I put code in there that tries to use a database that might not exist?**

**How do I put code in there that will cause an error if run directly but WILL NOT RUN unless conditions are appropriate.**

Please see the attached images.

Here's the code so you don't have to type it...

```
-- SQL SERVER: We can't run this script because CFPT does not exist.
-- ME: But it WILL exist after the first command runs
-- SQL SERVER: That does not matter - at THIS point in the code... it does not exist... tough luck



-- CREATE THE DATABASE
create database CFPT

-- USE THE DATABASE
USE CFPT

use master
drop database CFPT
```

Second code snippet:

```
-- SQL SERVER: We can't run this script because CFPT does not exist.
select db_id('CFPT') -- this just lets us see what the IF statement is going to have to deal with

IF db_id('CFPT') is null 
    begin
        print 'DESIRED DB DOES NOT EXIST' 
        return
    end
else
    begin
        use CFPT -- this line of code makes the whole script just not run.
    end;

    -- doesn't want to work - chokes on the use databasename (when the database does not exist)
```

(EDIT 1 start ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////)

A **third image** was added with this edit - The **SECOND image** shows that the if/then/else statement will not work.  The **3rd image** shows that the database CFPT is not in the database list (left side of image) and the select statement was run (top highlighed code) and the results of that select (bottom red circle)

**How do I get the if/then/else statement to work? (Because the THEN will not run if the conditions are not favorable shall-we-say)**

(for some reason the red wavy lines are not showing up - they should be but they aren't - hmmm)

(EDIT 1 end ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////)

(EDIT 2 start ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////)

In relation to this question - trying to segregate commands that would normally fail but will not be attempted to be executed unless conditions are just right.....   (see 4th image below) **I'm segregating some commands with an IF statement (IF 1=2) but SQL Server is going into that IF statement even though the condition is false.  Why is that?**

(EDIT 2 end ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////)

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
-- CREATE THE DATABASE
create database CFPT
GO
-- USE THE DATABASE
USE CFPT

use master
drop database CFPT
```

The GO command is a batch terminator, it separates the command to create the database from the command to use it.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

and

[What is the use of GO in SQL Server Management Studio & Transact SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio-transact-sql)

Comment: **Thanks, JSR!**  That worked really nice. Can you provide any insight to the 2nd part of my OP?  The part that had the code with the if/then/else statement?  I will be adding an additional image - in the additional image it shows that the database does not exist (select statement that returns null) yet the if/then/else fails.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get the second script to work in it's current form.  You simply cannot USE database if it doesn't exist at the start of the batch.  Can you check if your db exists with some other mechanism and use that to determine which script to run?

Comment: I'll probably have to do something like that. (**_check if your db exists with some other mechanism and use that to determine which script to run_**)   ... I'm just used to writing programs where I say "If it's available, use it, otherwise do something else"  and if it was not available it would not give me any errors but MsSS is giving me that error in this case - bummer.  :-(

Comment: It was still giving me grief so I decided to do it a less than awesome way of doing it - I commented out all the undo commands and made the script only a "create" script - so it would create the db and all the tables - one shot - if the user wanted to undo everything they'd have to highlight each of the undo commands - drop database etc and run each command separately...

(**use master**) // (**ALTER DATABASE DataBaseNameHere SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;**) // (**drop database DataBaseNameHere**)   -- I had to "get the job done" so elegance went out the window.

Comment: I wouldn't say that having more than one script is inelegant or less than awesome.