# Create and handle several DBs in SQL Server (2017) from Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm developing a desktop app to organize different events, thus creating a DB for each event. So far, I've managed to create a DB with whatever name the user wants, using a simple GUI.

However, I can't create tables nor columns for said database, even though it's exactly the same syntax I use in SQL Server Manager.

My code so far:

```
public static void creDB(String db_name, String table_name){

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt =  null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

            String SQL = "CREATE DATABASE " + db_name;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            int result = stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);

            String SQL3 = "USE " + db_name;
            boolean ree = stmt.execute(SQL3);
            String SQL4 = "GO";
            boolean rr = stmt.execute(SQL4);

            if (result == 0){
                System.out.println("Se insertó :D!");
                String SQL2 = "CREATE TABLE Pepe(Name_emp INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)";
                int res = stmt.executeUpdate(SQL2);
                if (res == 0)
                    System.out.println("GRACIAS DIOS");
            }else
                System.out.println("Raios shico");


        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
            if (rs != null) try {rs.close();} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            if (stmt != null) try {stmt.close();} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            if (conn != null) try {conn.close();} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
```

The error I get is when I try to ***actually use the DB***, using the `use [DB name] go`; I tried already using that same syntax in *one* single SQL statement, however it didn't work, so I tried doing it separately and got this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'GO'.

I know the code above looks like a mess, and it is, but it's just for testing purposes since I'm new to doing DB-related projects with Java; I mixed-matched some of the concepts of [this site](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-tutorial-sql-insert-select-update-and-delete-examples), which were successful up until the creation of the tables.

I **know** there's a better way of managing several databases, but as I said, I'm just starting so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: GO is only for  SQL server Management Studio. When using in Java the command is executed by stmt.executeUpdate(sqlcommand).
The equivalent of the 'use' in JDBC is within the connection URL; jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;databaseName=DATABASE.

Comment: Sir, I can't thank you enough for that simple explanation that I couldn't find anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use statements like `USE <dbname>` when using JDBC, it may lead to unexpected behavior because parts of the driver may still use metadata for the original connected database. You should either use `setCatalog` on the current connection to switch databases or create an entirely new connection to the new database.

In short, after creating the database, you should use:

```
conn.setCatalog(db_name);
```

That's it.

Also, `go` is not part of the SQL Server syntax, it is only used by tools like the Management Studio, see [What is the use of GO in SQL Server Management Studio & Transact SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio-transact-sql) The equivalent in JDBC is to simply execute the statement.