# Must declare the scalar variable - even though that variable is defined (Q&A)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a query, but I keep getting the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@userId".

But as you can see from the sql below (simplified example), that variable is declared.

```
declare @userId uniqueidentifier = '76652631-bd15-22b2-1a00-6ae6ee1e101a'

USE MyDatabase
GO

SELECT * FROM [User] where UserId = @userId
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that that 'GO' statement is a [terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio-transact-sql), so after it's executed, the variable (created above it, but used below it) no longer exists.

Change your code to the following and it will work.

```
USE MyDatabase
GO

declare @userId uniqueidentifier = '76652631-bd15-22b2-1a00-6ae6ee1e101a'

SELECT * FROM [User] where UserId = @userId
```