# How to handle query batches in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am currently experimenting with creating and executing stored procedures from Python using SQLAlchemy, and I keep running into this error: "X must be the first statement in a query batch". From reading up on the topic, these "query batches" should be separated by "GO", but "GO" in not supported in SQLAlchemy where I get the following error "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'".

#### Working SQL code

```
USE my_database;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE test.test_procedure  
AS   
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM my_other_database.my_schema.my_table;
```

#### Not Working SQLAlchemy

```
# Creating Identical Query
identical_query = """
USE my_database;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE test.test_procedure  
AS   
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM my_other_database.my_schema.my_table;   
"""

# Creating engine
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
my_engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{self.db_server}/{self.db_name}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={self.db_driver}")
```

Now let's try to execute the command in various ways as suggested on different forums.

```
# Execution 1
my_engine.execute(identical_query)

# Execution 2
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
my_engine.execute(text(identical_query))

# Execution 3
with sql_con.db_engine.connect() as con:
    query = text(identical_query)
    con.execute(query)
```

None of the ways work, and I just keep getting the error "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'". Shouldn't SQLAlchemy be able to execute the same SQL code that works as is in the SQL database?

Comment: You might want `conn.exec_driver_sql(sql)` - review [these docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#working-with-driver-sql-and-raw-dbapi-connections).

Comment: It results in the same error (if I no longer wrap the sql string in text())

Comment: FYI `GO` is not a sql keyword. It only works in SSMS (!). SSMS never sends a GO command to SQL Server - it uses it to separate batches. So you should not put GO in raw sql text sent to SQL Server [sql-server-utilities-statements-go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go) Having a USE statement in there seems strange to me too ... not so sure, but generally you would connect to a database and run the command to create the stored procedure, not switch databases in your sql text you are running.

Comment: I am aware of your point regarding two database, but in my case I connect to a server with multiple databases, and one database is created for the purpose of testing, so I have to do it this way.  But I guess the conclusion has to be that "GO" is a no-go :P

Comment: Yes, `go` is a no-go lol. Also Create Procedure must be the first statement in a create procedure batch ... so `use` is also a no-go. You have to connect to the correct database and run the command there.

Comment: Details on GO here: [what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio-transact-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio-transact-sql)

Comment: I actually ran into that before, but then I also saw some answers on stackoverflow where "GO" was in the queries, and I though that it would work anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @topsail in the comments **GO** is not an SQL keyword, but it is a keyword unique to "SQL Server Management Studio", where it is used to break queries into batches.

In SQLAlchemy the same functionality can be achieved by breaking up the SQL script by GO, and then using **sessions** to execute the commands within the same context. See example:

```
# Imports
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# Creating a database engine
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server")

# Breaking into batches
q1, q2 = identical_query.split("GO\n")

# create session and add objects
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute(q1)
    session.execute(q2)
    session.commit()
```