# SQL Server seems to behave in an async manner

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, rbar

I know SQL statements don't execute asynchronously by default, but I have a situation that appears to behave that way.

**Tables**

- `[#data]`
- `[tbl_Bucket]`
- `[tbl_IDPool]`

**Procedures**

- `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]`
- `[sp_GenerateID]`
- `[sp_UpdateIDPool]`

**Process**

- An application calls `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]`
- `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]` calls `[sp_GenerateID]`
- `[sp_GenerateID]` queries `[tbl_IDPool]` and generates a value
- `[sp_GenerateID]` calls `[sp_UpdateIDPool]`
- `[sp_UpdateIDPool]` writes to `[tbl_IDPool]`
- `[sp_GenerateID]` returns its generated value to `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]`
- `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]` uses the value as a primary key for a new record in `[tbl_Bucket]`
- `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]` returns the generated value to the caller

**Scenario**

`[#data]` has information (1500 - 12000 records) destined for `[tbl_Bucket]`. Since `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]` can only handle one record at a time, the process is RBAR'ed - for each record in `[#data]` `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]` is called.

**Problem**

`[sp_GenerateID]` generates duplicate values. I've had anything from 13 to 130 duplicate generated values before the actual `INSERT` in `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]` occurs and the error is thrown.

The generated value is dependent on the data in `[tbl_IDPool]` and it is therefore also important that `[sp_UpdateIDPool]` be called for each `[sp_GenerateID]` call to ensure the *next* `[sp_GenerateID]` call generates a unique value.

I suspect it has something to do with `[sp_GenerateID]` being called a second time before `[sp_UpdateIDPool]` could finish writing to `[tbl_IDPool]`. But this doesn't make sense because the RBAR should wait for `[sp_InsertIntoBucket]` which should wait for `[sp_GenerateID]` which should wait for `[sp_UpdateIDPool]` before moving to the next `[#data]` entry, right?

**What I've tried**

- `WAITFOR DELAY "00:00:00.003"` - This works, but I'm looking for a better, more efficient, more elegant solution.
- `WHILE` vs. `CURSOR` - The only difference is that the `CURSOR` is slightly slower.
- With and without `WITH (NOLOCK)` in the `[sp_GenerateID]` query of `[tbl_IDPool]` hoping a write (first call) would lock a read (second call).

Comment: You should avoid using `sp_` on the start of stored procedure names. There are warnings in the documentation about this being reserved for Microsoft's *system* procedures, and if there's a name clash (either now, or possibly if the system is updated later), the Microsoft one will "win".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is interesting. Thanks for the heads-up. I was not aware of that and will do so in future - or should I say *not* do so. In this case, however, it was merely to distinguish between entity types. Your warning has been noted.

Comment: You have concurrency between different transactions, right? Why do you think there is intra-transaction asynchrony? A race condition seems to explain this behavior well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time; I appreciate your input. I wasn't expecting SQL Server to behave in this way because the RBAR-loop is initiating the "call stack" to all the other procedures. It [the top-level, outer session] can't be concurrent to itself, can it? Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: A single query to SQL Server never creates concurrency (this cna be annoying if you actually *want* parallelism). When you call a proc that call is synchronous and blocking. I'm nut sure whether you have said it or not, but most likely multiple transactions (in different sessions) are operating on the same data here. Try the SERIALIZABLE suggestion from the answer to test that theory. SERIALIZABLE provides the illusion of single-threaded execution.

Comment: Precisely. I was expecting the call to be synchronous. But the first call to `[sp_GenerateID]` generates `ABC001` and the second call also generates `ABC001` while I am expecting it to generate `ABC002`. That tells me that the second call to `[sp_GenerateID]` was made before the first call to `[sp_GenerateID]` could call `[sp_UpdateIDPool]`. I tried the `ISOLATION LEVEL` suggestion; please see my comment on that answer.

Comment: The procedure runs synchronously, period. There must be some bug in it. I did not understand from your comment what the result of your SERIALIZABLE test was. At this point there is not enough information to find the issue. Your best bet would be to create an executable repro by copying the database and deleting code until the issue is condensed to a few dozen lines. (Post any code in general would also help.)

Comment: Show your are RBAR.  And do you only have one active RBAR.  That should synchronous.  You need to have each sp write the sp_GenerateID,  timestamp, and name of sp to a log table to prove that is happening.  You have something else going on.

Comment: Why couldn't you use an identity field rather than calling a stored procedure to generate a unique id?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of `[sp_GenerateID]` try specifying

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

Then enclose the remaining contents in transaction block.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to respond. I tried the statement you suggested in a few different places but kept getting `Incorrect syntax near 'SERIALIZABLE'.` so I Googled it and got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342732/tsql-mutual-exclusive-access-in-a-stored-procedure