# Don't understand error message: Must declare the scalar variable "@Username".

Tags: sql

I have a simple script updating and showing a useraccount. (working with the management studio 2010)
For preventing user errors I wanna use a variable in SQL (never did this before).

When reading tutorials it should be as simple as codesample below except I i'm getting an error message. Searching the web for people with the same error, I end up seeing very complex code with the same error. Can someone give me a clue.

```
DECLARE @Username nvarchar(256) 
Set @Username = 'theUsername'

UPDATE aspnet_Membership
SET IsLockedOut = 0
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT U.UserId
FROM aspnet_Users as U inner join aspnet_Membership M on U.UserId = M.UserId
WHERE u.UserName = @Username)
GO 
SELECT U.UserId, U.UserName, M.Password, M.IsLockedOut, U.LastActivityDate
FROM aspnet_Users as U inner join aspnet_Membership M on U.UserId = M.UserId
WHERE u.UserName = @Username
```

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@Username".

Comment: Might be a case sensitivity problem with your variable naming..Recheck your sql script..

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The scope of variable in Transact-SQL is limited by batch.
Your script contains two batches separated by "GO"

Comment: +1 for being clear 'Your script contains two batches separated by "GO"'

Answer (score 6):

There is a `GO` inside your script, `GO` divides your script into two batches so have to re-define all used variables after `GO`, because the scope is limited to this batch.

BTW: I don't think, that this `GO` is necessary, isn't it?

Thanks to @gbn and @alexm giving hint, that `GO` separate statements into batches and not into transactions, see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: What do you mean writing *transactions*? AFAIK `GO` has nothing in common with transactions (in strictly database meaning).

Comment: What i say, I'm rather new to SQL. When DO I need the GO statement?

Comment: @LuukKrijnen: http://stackoverflow.com/q/971177/27535 for example. Also, alexm's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @rabudde: this is incorrect in several ways: GO is a client side directive that separates batches. Not transactions. The DB server doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

`GO` separates batches and is a **client** instruction, not a **server** one. So the server receives the second batch separately as a new query and in this the variable is not declared.

If you try to do the following you will get an error, because the server does not understand the command `GO`:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000);
SET @SQL = 'PRINT ''hello'';
GO
PRINT ''goodbye'';';
```

The server won't split this into two batches, because batches are things submitted to the server by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Once you write GO, @Username is not available to SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

you have to redefine `@Username` after `GO` statement