# Best Practice for Repeating SQL Statements

Tags: sql, sybase

I am looking for a better approach to writing highly repetitive sql statements.  I know I can do this by, for example, using PHP methods, but I would like a pure SQL solution.  I am using Sybase.

```
select
"SvHKeyId"=sh.KeyId,
"Scale"="Partial PTSD",
"ScoreText"=convert(varchar(3),
    (case
        when
            (case
                when
                    1 in (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum between 1 and 13)
                    and 1 in (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum between 15 and 21)
                    and 1 in (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum between 22 and 26)
                then 'Yes'
                else 'No'
            end)
        = 'Yes'
        and
        (case
            when
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=30) >= 2
                        or (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=32) >= 2
                        or (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=33) >= 2
                        or (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=29) >= 2
                        or (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=45) >= 2
                    then 1
                    else 0
                end)
                +
                (case
                    when
                        (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=36) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=44) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=42) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=34) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=35) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                    >= 3 then 1
                    else 0
                end)
                +
                (case
                    when
                        (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=40) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=43) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=28) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=39) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                    >= 2 then 1
                    else 0
                end)
            >=2
            then 'Yes'
            else 'No'
        end)
        = 'Yes'
        then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
    end)
    ),
 "ScoreNum"=
    (case
        when
            (case
                when
                    1 in (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum between 1 and 13)
                    and 1 in (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum between 15 and 21)
                    and 1 in (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum between 22 and 26)
                then 'Yes'
                else 'No'
            end)
        = 'Yes'
        and
        (case
            when
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=30) >= 2
                        or (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=32) >= 2
                        or (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=33) >= 2
                        or (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=29) >= 2
                        or (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=45) >= 2
                    then 1
                    else 0
                end)
                +
                (case
                    when
                        (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=36) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=44) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=42) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=34) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=35) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                    >= 3 then 1
                    else 0
                end)
                +
                (case
                    when
                        (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=40) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=43) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=28) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                        + (case when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=39) >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
                    >= 2 then 1
                    else 0
                end)
            >=2
            then 'Yes'
            else 'No'
        end)
        = 'Yes'
        then 1
        else 0
    end)
from
    SurvHeader sh
where
    sh.KeyId=105101
```

This is a scoring procedure.  I am comparing a series of sub-scores to derive an overall score.  Is there a better SQL approach?  I suppose I could use a stored procedure?

Here is an even more extreme example where I use so many subqueries I exceed the limit:

```
select
"SvHKeyId"=sh.KeyId,
"Scale"="Total",
"ScoreText"=convert(varchar(3),
       (select sum(Resp) from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId
       and QuestNum in (28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,39,40,42,43,44,45,46) and Resp <> 5)
       + 
       (case
            when
                (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37) <> 5
                and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38) <> 5
            then
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                        > (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                        < (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                        = (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                end)
            else
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37) = 5
                        and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38) = 5
                    then 0
                    else
                        (case
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                            else 0
                        end)
                 end)
        end)
        +
       (case
            when
                (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31) <> 5
                and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47) <> 5
            then
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                        > (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                        < (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                        = (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                end)
            else
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31) = 5
                        and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47) = 5
                    then 0
                    else
                        (case
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                            else 0
                        end)
                 end)
        end)
        +
       (case
            when
                (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46) <> 5
                and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48) <> 5
            then
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                        > (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                        < (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                        = (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                end)
            else
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46) = 5
                        and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48) = 5
                    then 0
                    else
                        (case
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                            else 0
                        end)
                 end)
        end)
    ),
 "ScoreNum"=
       (select sum(Resp) from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId
       and QuestNum in (28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,39,40,42,43,44,45,46) and Resp <> 5)
       + 
       (case
            when
                (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37) <> 5
                and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38) <> 5
            then
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                        > (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                        < (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                        = (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                end)
            else
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37) = 5
                        and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38) = 5
                    then 0
                    else
                        (case
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38)
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=38) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=37)
                            else 0
                        end)
                 end)
        end)
        +
       (case
            when
                (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31) <> 5
                and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47) <> 5
            then
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                        > (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                        < (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                        = (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                end)
            else
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31) = 5
                        and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47) = 5
                    then 0
                    else
                        (case
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47)
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=47) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=31)
                            else 0
                        end)
                 end)
        end)
        +
       (case
            when
                (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46) <> 5
                and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48) <> 5
            then
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                        > (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                        < (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                        = (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                    then
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                end)
            else
                (case
                    when
                        (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46) = 5
                        and (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48) = 5
                    then 0
                    else
                        (case
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48)
                            when (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=48) = 5
                            then (select Resp from SurvResp sr where sh.KeyId=sr.SvHKeyId and sr.QuestNum=46)
                            else 0
                        end)
                 end)
        end)
from
    SurvHeader sh
where sh.KeyId=105101
```

Comment: "I would like a pure SQL solution" - why? what you currently do is pretty much unreadable...

Comment: Perhaps pure SQL is not the way to go.  The reason I wanted to explore this was that with a pure SQL solution the scoring procedure becomes independent of the application - so it is more portable.

Comment: And similarly, you could say that this SQL code is very restircting, moving the logic to the application would create a solution that's independent of the SQL engine... Or, in short, it boils down to this: do you need that independence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these literals should be data, not code.  I strongly recommend refactoring these giant switches into data so a much simpler query can evaluate it.  A "pure SQL" solution would then be much more feasible, and both performance and maintenance will be better in the long run.  Maybe a `Scoring` table that you can join on and compare to?

`Scoring (Question, Answer, Result)` is one conceptual possibility, hopefully not too oversimplified.

As has been said, ["You can write FORTRAN in any language."](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/you-can-write-fortran-in-any-language.html)

Even T-SQL, it seems.

**UPDATE**

If these calculations have already been done and you've updated tables within your current transaction, there is no need to re-do them simply because they aren't committed yet. Any query within this transaction will get this transaction's updated data if it was updated earlier in the transaction.

More on [Sybase ASE transactions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug843.htm).

Also, you shouldn't expect `GO` to [work in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971177/using-go-within-a-transaction).  It is used as a batch separator in your IDE, not transaction control.

Comment: They actually are being saved as data into a scoring table - previous queries are generating scores for the same sub-scales in an earlier statement.  Perhaps my folly was doing it in the same transaction - because I cannot select the result until the transaction is complete - which is why I had the redundancy.  Is there a way to select a value from a transaction that is not yet committed when you are in that same transaction?  Otherwise I could potentially have orphan values if I use separate transactions and something goes awry.

Comment: It would still seem to me that you'd want to represent all of these `case`s as rows in a table.

Comment: While you're inside a transaction, all of the prior changes done within that transaction will be visible to you.

Comment: I believe referencing the sub-scores I already scored would be more effective - it would greatly reduce the amount of switches without fragmenting the sql statements unnecessarily.

Comment: So if I..."begin transaction insert into table select 'KeyId'=123, 'Score'=45  go select * from table where KeyId = 123 ...I can get the score?

Comment: I wouldn't use `GO` [inside a transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971177/using-go-within-a-transaction) like that, but you will get the inserted record from that select while you're within that transaction. No harm in actually trying it, yeah?

Comment: Indeed - was just a dumb example, and yes I tested it a second after posting :).  Thank you very much for solving my issue.  Can you please add something about transactions to your answer and I'll accept it!