# How to execute an .sql file in pymssql

Tags: python, database, file, pymssql

I'm trying to execute an sql file in python using pymssql, this file contains a BEGIN TRANSACTION, a COMMIT TRANSACTION and an END, and some safety nets before and after.

I'm trying to open the file in memory and execute the content:

```
file = open(options.sqlFile, 'r')
sqlFileContents = file.read()
file.close()

cursor.execute(sqlFileContents)
conn.commit()
```

But it's returning me errors:

```
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.DB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 1
5:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity     
15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102,severity 
15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

So basically I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to execute the query the way I'm doing it?
2. is the sql query file itself the problem?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Here is the SQL:

Here is the SQL:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT,             QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE     id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
PRINT N'Adding Release Version to [admin].[ReleaseHistory]'
GO
INSERT INTO [admin].[ReleaseHistory] VALUES (GetUTCDate(), '1.7')
GO
IF @@ERROR<>0 AND @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT=0 BEGIN INSERT INTO #tmpErrors (Error) SELECT 1 BEGIN     TRANSACTION END
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT 'The database update succeeded'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT 'The database update failed'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do it like that.
I often do so, it is cleaner that hardcoding the SQL in your code.

Can you add the SQL to your post? there's probably a messed up character somewhere.

I do it like that (with pyodbc):

```
with open('%smysql.sql' % SQL_DIR) as f: 
            sql = f.read() % params # Don't do that with untrusted inputs
            cursor.execute(sql)
            cursor.commit()
            cursor.close()
```

EDIT: Remove all the `GO` it's not an real SQL statement.
Check this answer: [Using "GO" within a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971177/using-go-within-a-transaction).

Then it should be fine.