# XACT_ABORT not rolling back a transaction on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here is a simple test I coded.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_MyTest1]
AS
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_MyTest1]
AS
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_MyTest2]
AS
GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

It was my understanding that since I have `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, when the second create procedure fails, the entire transaction will roll back.  Instead, only things proceeding the error (the first create procedure) are rolled back and the last create procedure executes just fine.  I then get a message saying `The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.`

I've seen people have an issue with RAISEERROR, but the documentation for XACT_ABORT says that RAISEERROR does not honnor XACT_ABORT.  But this doesn't mention anything about an error such as creating a duplicate procedure not honoring XACT_ABORT.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql

> The THROW statement honors SET XACT_ABORT RAISERROR does not. New Applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.

This is with SQL Server 2012, if that is relevant.

Comment: See this answer by Remus Rusanu:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178270/can-we-use-go-multiple-times-in-sql-transaction

Comment: See this as well for more details:http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#scope-abortion

Comment: Transactions are run time constructs, not lexical constructs. When the transaction is rolled back, then create of `usp_MyTest2` proceeds in its own transaction, presumably with auto-commit. The transaction does not span from create to commit/rollback from analyzing the text. Also, `xact-abort` will abort the batch, but `go` is a batch separator, so last create is in its own batch.

Answer (score 4):

It *does* rollback the transaction.

You can see this quite clearly with

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, 'Point1'
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_MyTest1] AS
GO
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, 'Point2'
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_MyTest1] AS
GO
/*
  The earlier transaction has now been rolled back and 
  now running outside an explicit transaction. @@TRANCOUNT is 0
 */
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, 'Point3'
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_MyTest2] AS
GO
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, 'Point4'
GO
/*Nothing to commit so error*/
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Which returns

[image]

By the time you get to point 3 the transaction has been rolled back (including the initial creation of `usp_MyTest1`) and the creation of `usp_MyTest2` happens in a new [auto commit transaction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878(v=sql.105).aspx). So the end result is the database contains `usp_MyTest2` and not `usp_MyTest1` assuming neither were there at the start.

Which is why you also see the error at the end

> Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 The COMMIT TRANSACTION request
>   has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

To terminate the script execution after an error has occurred and the transaction is rolled back (instead of ploughing on and executing subsequent batches) the most reliable method is to enable sqlcmd mode in SSMS and add this to the top of the script `:on error exit`