# How to switch database context to newly created database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, sql-scripts

I wrote a script to create a database:

> 1: USE master;
>   2: IF (db_id('myDB') is null)
>   3:     CREATE DATABASE myDB;
>   4: USE myDB;

but it does not work... I got an error: **Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'myDB'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. (Msg *911*)**

Where is my mistake?

Thanks.

**ANSWER:**
[go go go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)
**USEFUL LINK:** [Without using GO, programmatically, you would need to make 2 separate database calls.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784953/318499)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [GO statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) after line 3.  That will force execution of the previous script.

Answer (score 7):

It works if you separate your statements with a `go`

```
USE master;
go
IF (db_id('myDB') is null)
  CREATE DATABASE myDB;
go  
USE myDB;
```